# Why is the angle between vectors restricted?

Tags: vectors, angle

Why is the calculated angle between two vectors always between $\pi$ and $0$.

Is this due to the limitations of $\arccos\theta$ or is it because angles between vectors is described to be the smaller one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of tradition and simplicity.

Each pair of vectors defines two angles. One of them is between $0$ and $\pi$ and the other is between $\pi$ and $2\pi$. Since their sum is $2\pi$, we only really need to tell *one* of the two angles, and we decide, for simplicity, to always report the smaller of the two.

Comment: It might be worth additionally pointing out that in certain (?) settings, like the plane, we can make a canonical choice of the "direction of the angle", and thus report the angle from a vector to another to always be the one in positive (counter-clockwise) direction. In more general settings such a canonical direction is not available.

Answer (score 1):

There are angles of all possible degrees. In context with angles in a [triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_and_obtuse_triangles) however, we have $0\le \theta \le \pi$.